# Understanding environmental variables in different contexts

Tags: shell, process, environment-variables, locale

Trying to understand the behaviour of the environment in Linux (Ubuntu 13.04 concretely), I've find different situations where setting envirionment variables are used or defined for/in different contexts. For example, if I check, `locale`, I get:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_ES:es_HN:es_EC:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8
// more output
```

But, if I find, for example, `LC_CTYPE` using `env | grep "LC_CTYPE"`, it sends no output. In general, `locale` shows me 13 `LC_*` variables and `env` only nine:

```
$ locale | grep "LC_*" | wc -l
13
$ env | grep "LC_*" | wc -l
9
```

Other variable with different "nature" is `PS1`. For example:

```
$ env | grep "PS1" # No output, but...
$ set | grep "PS1" | head -n 1
PS1=$'\\[\\033[1;33m\\][\\t][\\W]\342\230\233\\[\\033[0m\\] '
```

and of course, `PS1` is a well-defined variable in my current environment, since I see my prompt changed accordingly.

Other way of *viewing* environment variables in other context is by means of `strace`. It is a program which allows you to see what's going on when you execute a program. Sample:

```
$ strace -v ./a.out # a.out is a common Hello World, made in C.
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], ["LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8", ...]) = 0
brk(0)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
# etc, etc
write(1, "Hello World\n", 12Hello World
)           = 12
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

The first thing the shell makes when executing a program, is call to `execve`, which does really call a program. Its first argument is the program being called, the second is the `argv` params of the called program, and the third parameter is the environment variables.

In that 3rd parameter, for example, doesn't appear either `PS1` or `LC_TYPE`.

In general, variables appearing in `env` or `set` appear in the list of environment variables sent to `execve`. Some `locale` variables appear in `env` or `set` but others not (`LC_TYPE`, `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_MESSAGE`, as well as `LC_ALL` but with an empty value). Lastly, other variables are not defined in `env` although they have a visible effect (`PS1`), as reflected by `set`.

What's going on here? What are the differences between `env`, `set` (without arguments), `locale` (obviously respect to locale variables only)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The primary issue here -- which accounts for why, e.g., `$PS1` is not reported by `env` -- is that `env` is reporting from a *non-interactive* environment.  Processes are executed from a fork of your *interactive* shell, but there's a subtlety involved in how their environment is set: It's actually inherited via a native C level external variable set for all `exec()`'d processes (see `man environ`).  Here's an illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char **environ;

int main (void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", environ[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What's interesting about this is, if you compile and run it, you'll find the contents of `**environ` exactly match the one reported by `env`:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out > aout.txt
$ env > env.txt
$ diff env.txt aout.txt
68c68
< _=/bin/env
---
> _=./a.out
```

The only difference is the name of the executable.  So where does `**environ` come from and why doesn't it contain, e.g., `$PS1`?

The fundamental explanation is that process are always created as children of other processes and they inherit `**environ`, but `PS1` was never part of it. At start up, a shell may source variables from standard places, and those places differ depending on whether the shell is interactive or not; see **INVOCATION** in `man bash`.  An aspect of this is that:

> PS1 is set [...] **if bash is interactive,** allowing a shell
>   script or a startup file to test this state.

Now, notice in `/etc/bashrc` something like this:

```
# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
```

Which is where your actual (fancy) prompt is set, and neither it nor the initial value of `$PS1` were ever `export`ed.  The initial value was created by the shell at invocation because it was interactive, and then it sourced then that file -- but `PS1` did not get put into `**environ`.  You can see this if you execute:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $PS1
```

Nothing -- even though if you `echo $PS1` in your interactive shell it's defined.  This is because the `**environ` of the executed `#!/bin/sh` is the same as that of the parent interactive shell, but that does NOT contain `PS1`.  This implies each shell uses an internal table of global variables separate, but originally populated, from `**environ` (this is confusing, since it means `**environ` does not include many things referred to as *[environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)*).

The contents of `**environ` are in in `/proc/[PID]/environ`, and if you check that for your current interactive shell, `cat /proc/$BASHPID/environ`, you'll see `PS1` is not there.

## But how does stuff get into "environ"?

The simple answer is, via system calls.  For example, if we throw some stuff into the example C program from earlier:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char **environ;

int main (void) {
    int i;
    if (putenv("MYFOO=whatbar?")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "putenv() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", environ[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`MYFOO=whatbar?` will be in the output (see `man putenv`).  Since the shell creates processes by `fork()`ing (which duplicates the parent's memory stack) and then calling `execv()` (which passes on the duplicated `**environ`), we can see a mechanism by which environment variables may be `export`ed to child processes.

If you throw a `fork()` into that example, you'll see this is the case, and (to reiterate), this process of fork'ing and potentially exec'ing is how child processes are created and inherit `**environ` from their ancestors. `exec` calls replace the process image, but as per `man execv` and `man environ` (nb. some versions of the former do not refer to this), `**environ` is passed on by the system.

Here's a literal fork and exec of `/usr/bin/env` with `MYFOO=whatbar?` exported via `putenv()`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char **environ;

int main (void) {
    pid_t pid;

    if (putenv("MYFOO=whatbar?")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "putenv() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (!pid) execl("/usr/bin/env", "env", NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

## So where's the stuff that's not in "environ"?

It's private data of a particular shell instance.  Bash will show you this + the inherited environ stuff via `set` with no arguments.  Note this output also includes sourced functions.

> But, if I find, for example, LC_CTYPE using env | grep "LC_CTYPE", it sends no output. In general, locale shows me 13 LC_* variables and env only nine:

I get no `LC_` variables at all from `env` (just `LANG`) but 13 from `locale`.  I would presume these are variables set by a `locale` call and not exported; the fact that you get any from `env` perhaps reflects a naive error in some configuration somewhere.

Comment: Why do you draw the line around "non-interactive subshells"? `PS1="foo "; bash` Is the new bash not an "interactive subshell"?

Comment: Right, but that's not my point. My point is that interactive and non-interactive "subshells" (i.e. explicitely called shells) behave the same way.

Comment: I think you look at the wrong area here, mix up the two. The difference between exported and non-exported variables ends at the `execve()`. At that point new processes are all the same, whether it's `env` or `bash`. What happens **after** the `execve()` is special to the program. And it is irrelevant whether the program has been started from a shell or whatever. Shell invocation is IMHO completely irrelevant for understanding the export mechanism.

Comment: @Peregring-lk : All apologies for the previous ambiguities.  After being pushed by Mr. Laging, I did some deeper research and experimentation to discover where the apparent dependencies in environment come from, and have updated my answer with those, I think in-depth and definitive, findings!

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' Thanks for your complete replay; and finally, where can I see non-exported variables? In other words, where are grouped all variables including those not collected by `env`?

Comment: Those are private data maintained by the an individual shell process -- unlike the stuff in `**environ`, they aren't characteristics of processes generally so the system can't report them, e.g., in `/proc`.  However, the `set` command in `bash` without arguments will list all variables (including `PS1`) as well as sourced function definitions (which may be a lot).  That still for me does not include the stuff output by `locale`, though, which again I think is a bit of its own thing.

Answer (score 4):

The shell knows two types of variables:

1. "internal" variables which are known to the shell only (and to subshells)
2. exported variables, the "official" ones which are seen by `execve` and thus by `env`. The shell builtin `export` shows you the exported variables.

If you execute

```
export PS1
```

and repeat

```
env | grep "PS1"
```

then you see it. Variables can be exported during creation (`export foo=bar` instead of `foo=bar`), they can be exported automatically on creation or modification (`set -a`), they can be exported later (`var=foo; ...; export var`) and they can be "unexported" (`export -n var`).

If the shell creates "real" subshells (by `a|b`, `(a;b)`, `$(a)` and so on) it keeps several non-exported variables in order to avoid chaos.

Comment: +1 The fact that subshells inherit non-exported variables that other child processes do not is an interesting case, I guess accounted for by the fact that a subshell is a `fork` with no `exec`.  This also means "subshell" does not refer to subprocess shells executed via a shebang.  Thanks for arguing some of these points with me!

Answer (score 4):

The output from the `locale` command is not a list of environment variables from the current environment. It is a display of that process' effective locale settings (which is influenced in part by certain environment variables) and is presented in the same `key=value` format that the `env` command uses.

You can see the source for the eglibc `locale` command implementation here:
http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/eglibc-2_19/libc/locale/programs/locale.c?view=markup