# How to trace system calls being invoked after typing command?

Tags: shell, process, subshell

This question is relevant to [the question of 'what happens when we type a simple command on shell?'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123457/what-happens-when-we-type-a-simple-command-on-shell) I posted earlier. (I thought it would be better to post it separately. But if not, please let me know.)

I learned from [the previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123457/what-happens-when-we-type-a-simple-command-on-shell) that the shell built-in commands are treated specially and normal external commands are executed on child process.

This time, I would like to trace system calls such as fork, clone, or execve to monitor what really happened after typing command. But I can only trace an execve call `execve("bin/ls",,,) = 0` when I execute `strace` like this way.

```
strace -etrace=execve,clone ls
```

That means, as I guess, I can only monitor system calls which are called after a child process is created.

To monitor all system calls related to creating new process, What I have to do? To invoke command with `bash -c` like `strace -etrace=execve,clone bash -c '{ ls; }'`  would be helpful in this case?

Comment: @ThomasNyman Yes, my question seems to be dupulicate of the question you menentioned. I will read the answers carefully. Thanks

Comment: You need to add the `-f` (or `-ff`) option to strace for it the follow children. `strace -f -etrace=execve,clone bash -c '{ ls; }'` should do what you are looking for.

Comment: This should never have been closed as duplicate of the question it was - it is clearly about using strace to follow **children** rather than following shell builtins.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in one of the [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123461/48083) to your previous question, the `exec` family call happens after the child process is created, so if you want it to appear in the `strace` output then you have to make it also follow children of the shell process you are tracing.

You can do this by adding either the `-f` or `-ff` options, here are the relevant man page snippets:

```
 -f  Trace child processes as they are created by currently traced processes as a
     result of the fork(2) system call.
```

```
-ff  If the -o filename option is in effect, each processes trace is written to
     filename.pid where pid is the numeric process id of each process.  This is
     incompatible with -c, since no per-process counts are kept.
```

To trace the relevant calls involved in running a command in `bash` you can do:

```
strace -f -e trace=process bash -c 'ls; :'
```

The `-e trace=process` specifically traces all calls involved in process management. Also the second no-op command (`:`) is needed as if you run bash with only a single command, it is smart enough to just do an `execve` without forking since it knows it doesn't need to do anything else.