# Why is there no apparent clone or fork in simple bash command and how it's done?

Tags: shell, strace, syscalls

Consider the following (with `sh` being `/bin/dash`):

```
$ strace -e trace=process sh -c 'grep "^Pid:" /proc/self/status /proc/$$/status'
execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "grep \"^Pid:\" /proc/self/status /"...], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fcc8b661540) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fcc8b661810) = 24865
wait4(-1, /proc/self/status:Pid:    24865
/proc/24864/status:Pid: 24864
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 24865
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=24865, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

There's nothing unusual, `grep` replaced a forked process (here done via `clone()`) from main shell process. So far so good.

Now with bash 4.4:

```
$ strace -e trace=process bash -c 'grep "^Pid:" /proc/self/status /proc/$$/status'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "grep \"^Pid:\" /proc/self/status /"...], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f8416b88740) = 0
execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "^Pid:", "/proc/self/status", "/proc/25798/status"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f8113358b80) = 0
/proc/self/status:Pid:  25798
/proc/25798/status:Pid: 25798
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Here what's apparent is that `grep` assumes pid of the shell process and no apparent `fork()` or `clone()` call. Question is, then, how does `bash` achieve such acrobatics without either of the calls ?

Note, however, that `clone()` syscalls appears if the command contains shell redirection, such as `df > /dev/null`

Comment: Add another command after the `grep`. `bash` may be smart enough to not fork when only executing a single external command.

Comment: @Kusalananda  Yes. I dug through the source real quick, and it in fact has a flag `CMD_NO_FORK` if there's no pipes (and apparently no redirections)

Comment: Answered at least in part at the end of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123522/116858

Comment: @Kusalananda  It kinda answers, but it over summarizes stuff and the question asks entirely different thing (the linked post asks "How to trace stuff" while I'm asking "Why bash trace looks this way"). I was actually in the process of writing an answer to my own question.  I'll leave it here for now, since it's entirely not suitable for the linked duplicate, but actually does answer mine.

Comment: @Kusalananda [Hauke's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401082/85039) sseems inaccurate since bash shouldn't spawn a child process in the first place and shouldn't call `execve`  since `sleep` is built in, but [Homer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430052/85039) does appropriately answer it, but again just a brief summary. I guess I should have mentioned I was looking for exact mechanics on source code level. Would you say my answer be suitable as supporting Homers on that post ? I don't mind this post being closed. I got the answer either way

Comment: Voted to reopen so we can add @SergiyKolodyazhnyy's answer.

Comment: @dr01 Reopened it so it can have a better answer.

Comment: It seems that bash now follows the concept of `ksh93` that tries to avoid forks if possible.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430050/why-doesnt-spawn-a-new-child-process-when-run-in-background

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `sh -c 'command line'` are typically used by things like `system("command line")`, `ssh host 'command line'`, `vi`'s `!`, `cron`, and more generally anything that is used to interpret a command line, so it's pretty important to make it as efficient as possible.

Forking is expensive, in CPU time, memory, allocated file descriptors... Having a shell process lying about just waiting for another process before exiting is just a waste of resources. Also, it makes it difficult to correctly report the exit status of the separate process that would execute the command (for instance, when the process is killed).

Many shells will generally try to  minimize the number of forks as an optimisation. Even non-optimised shells like `bash` do it in the `sh -c cmd` or `(cmd in subshell)` cases. Contrary to ksh or zsh, it doesn't do it in `bash -c 'cmd > redir'` or  `bash -c 'cmd1; cmd2'` (same in subshells). ksh93 is the shell that goes furthest in avoiding forks.

There are cases where that optimisation cannot be done, like when doing:

```
sh < file
```

Where `sh` can't skip the fork for the last command, because more text could be appended to the  script whilst that command is running. And for non-seekable files, it can't detect the end-of-file as that could mean reading too much too early from the file.

Or:

```
sh -c 'trap "echo Ouch" INT; cmd'
```

Where the shell may have to run more commands after the "last" command has been executed.

Answer (score 9):

By digging through bash source code, I was able to figure out that bash in fact will ignore forking if there's no pipes or redirections. From [line 1601 in execute_cmd.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n1601):

```c
  /* If this is a simple command, tell execute_disk_command that it
     might be able to get away without forking and simply exec.
     This means things like ( sleep 10 ) will only cause one fork.
     If we're timing the command or inverting its return value, however,
     we cannot do this optimization. */
  if ((user_subshell || user_coproc) && (tcom->type == cm_simple || tcom->type == cm_subshell) &&
      ((tcom->flags & CMD_TIME_PIPELINE) == 0) &&
      ((tcom->flags & CMD_INVERT_RETURN) == 0))
    {
      tcom->flags |= CMD_NO_FORK;
      if (tcom->type == cm_simple)
    tcom->value.Simple->flags |= CMD_NO_FORK;
    }
```

Later those flags go to `execute_disk_command()` function, which sets up [nofork](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n5149) integer variable, which then later is [checked before attempting forking](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n5182). The actual command itself would be run by `execve()` wrapper [function shell_execve()](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n5264) from either forked or parent process, and in this case it's the actual parent.

The reason for such mechanic is well explained in [Stephane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466523/85039).

---

Side note outside the scope of this question: should be noted that apparently it matters whether the shell is interactive or running via `-c`. Prior to executing  the command there will be a fork. This is evident from running `strace` on interactive shell (`strace -e trace=process -f -o test.trace bash`) and checking the output file:

```
19607 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_t
idptr=0x7f2d35e93a10) = 19628
19607 wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
19628 execve("/bin/true", ["/bin/true"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
```

See also [Why bash does not spawn a subshell for simple commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466519/85039)