# From where is my script started on reboot

Tags: cron, raspbian, ps

Before some days I wrote a script and put it somewhere to get it started automatically on booting on my raspberry with wheezy.

`ps -ax` gives me:

```
 2041 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 2064 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
 2067 ?        S      0:00 /USR/SBIN/CRON
 2068 ?        S      0:00 /USR/SBIN/CRON
 2072 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c eibd -t 1023 -S -D -R -T -i --no-tunnel-cl...
 2073 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c python2.7 /opt/scripts/nibe_uplink/main.py
 2074 ?        S      0:00 eibd -t 1023 -S -D -R -T -i --no-tunnel-client-queuin...
 2075 ?        Rl     1:25 python2.7 /opt/scripts/nibe_uplink/main.py
```

pid 2074 is started from `/etc/crontab`.
pid 2075 is started from `crontab -e`

How can I find where pid 2073 is started from?

Comment: What do you mean by "located" and "where is it started"? Do you want to find out the working directory of your script? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What started this process?

You can use `ps` to find the parent of each process, either by adding `-l` (`ps -axl`) to give "long" output, or by specifically requesting the `ppid`:

```
ps -o ppid 2074
 PPID
2072
```

Repeat for 2072 to see what started that (probably CRON).

## Why two processes?

cron passes each command to a shell.   From [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html):

> The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a
>          "%" character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified
>          in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.

If you have the following line in `crontab`:

```
0 * * * * python2.7 /opt/some/script.py
```

...then when the entry needs to run (every hour, on the hour), cron executes the shell (`/bin/sh`) with the two arguments `-c` and `python2.7 /opt/some/script.py`.

The shell then interprets everything the item after '-c' as a command to run.  It finds `python2.7` from `PATH`, and executes it with the single argument `/opt/some/script.py`.  So, depending on your shell (including what `/bin/sh` points to), there may now be two processes running:

- `/bin/sh -c python2.7 /opt/some/script.py`
- `/usr/bin/python2.7 /opt/some/script.py`

That's why `ps` is showing you 2 `eibd` processes, and 2 `python2.7` ones, despite there being only one entry for each in your `crontab`.

Some shells may avoid forking a second process like this.  See [Why is there no apparent clone or fork in simple bash command and how it's done?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466496/why-is-there-no-apparent-clone-or-fork-in-simple-bash-command-and-how-its-done)

Comment: The icing on this particular cake can be found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466496/ .  So this is definitely not the Bourne Again shell, and is most likely the default `/bin/sh`, the Debian Almquist shell.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification. I thought there were two separate processes. The hint with PPID was very helpful. The chain for eibd is e.g.: 2074 -> 2072 -> 2067 -> 2064 -> 1 (init) -> 0

Comment: @JdeBP Good find, thankyou; edited to include a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this link](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/) tells me that there are multiple ways to run scripts on boot for the raspberry pi. In summation they are:

1. rc.local
2. .bashrc
3. init.d directory
4. SYSTEMD
5. crontab

Seeing as you've already checked cron try looking at 1-4.