# Unable to read more than 1024 chars on ZSH + MacOS

Tags: zsh, macos, read

Trying to read a long input into a variable from ZSH on MacOS.

```
    echo "URL: "
    read URL
```

input is always truncated to 1024 chars... if I try and type additional chars nothing happens.

- Input is copy/pasted from PostMan, its an S3 signed upload URL
- If I try and delete a few chars from the end (after pasting) I am only able to manually type as many chars as I deleted
- I tried using the `-n` option to no avail (nothing gets read into the variable)

How can I read a long input? ~1500 chars

Comment: hm, interesting, it works for me (Linux, middle-mouse copy and paste into `read`, as well as writing into an fd and `read`ing that: `< <(for i in {1..1500}; do printf "%d" $(( i % 10 )); done; printf "\n") read URL`, then `printf '%s' $URL | wc` yields 1500).

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the way you're giving characters to the `read URL` command.  Are you truly typing 1500 characters on your keyboard, or are you using a mouse to copy from one window (where the displayed text is wrapped) and paste into the window where your `read` command is running?  Are there carriage return or Control-D characters in the URL you're typing?

Comment: updated with additional info per the comments

Comment: Related: [Terminal does not accept pasted or typed lines of more than 1024 characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204815/170373), and similarly on Linux [Is there any limit on line length when pasting to a terminal in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/643777/170373) (4096 B)

Answer (score 0):

`read` itself just reads bytes from the terminal, it has no control over how the terminal reads those bytes. And the terminal has a limited line length which, as far as I recall, can't be changed easily (or at all?). The terminal's line editor is also very crude, just supporting backspace and not other editing commands.

Use [`vared`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vared) instead. This is somewhat similar to `read` (but with different options), but it's specialized to reading from a terminal and it uses zsh's line editor. That makes it a lot more user-friendly, in addition to not having a line length limit.

```
URL=
vared -p "URL: " URL
```

`vared` always reads from the terminal, not from standard input. If you want to support reading input redirected from a file or pipe, check whether standard input is a terminal with the `-t` [condition](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions)..

```
URL=
if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
  vared -p "URL: " URL
else
  read -r URL
fi
```