# Can not set the LC_TIME variable for the current process

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, locale

On Linux Mint Rebecca,
my current LC_TIME setting is `LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"`

I would like to execute `date` and watch how the current date is displayed in a Chinese format with Chinese characters.

Therefore, I thought I have to set the LC_TIME variable this way:

```
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

however, when I execute `date` I still get the date in the English style format, moreover when I execute `locale` I see the LC_TIME variable did not change its value at all.

Output of `locale -a`:

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

Comment: On what distribution? What is the output of `locale -a`?

Comment: C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX

Comment: On what distribution? You need to generate the `zh_CN.UTF-8` locale; how to do that depends on the distribution.

Comment: it is linux mint codename rebecca

Answer (score 3):

`date` is separate from your shell, so unless you instruct your shell to modify the environment `date` sees, your changes to `LC_TIME` won't have any effect.

You can fix this in two ways; either by specifying a value for `LC_TIME` only for `date`:

```
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8 date
```

or by exporting `LC_TIME` so its new value is given to all subsequent processes started by the shell:

```
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
export LC_TIME
date
```

You'll find more detail in [Understanding environmental variables in different contexts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123383/understanding-environmental-variables-in-different-contexts)

Comment: LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8;
export LC_TIME;
date           did work in so far that LC_TIME variable indeed changed its value, but the date command still display an english formatted time.

Comment: I had to use `LC_ALL` for it to work. (Setting `LANG` and `LC_TIME`did not work).

Comment: @thomasa88 that suggests you already had `LC_ALL` set to something else — it overrides all other `LC_` values. If you unset `LC_ALL`, `LC_TIME` should work fine.