# How to find the config file stored GLOBAL variable?

Tags: filesystems, environment-variables

If we run `export -p`, then we can find all global variable in the current system. But I think the variable list must be in a certain config file. How to find out it in my `CentOS 7` or `Ubuntu 16.04`?

Comment: @muru It cannot response my question. Such as I run `export test_variable="/usr/sbin"`. I even cannot find any file by `grep -R "test_variable" /etc`

Comment: Why would that variable be in any file? You created it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196586/environment-variables-where-are-they-saved-in